# Why do I have different IP addresses on bond0, en01 and enp2s0?

Tags: network-bonding

I set up a network bonding for failsafe in Ubuntu 18.04 according to this netplan:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: no
        enp2s0:
            dhcp4: no
    bonds:
        bond0:
            addresses: [192.168.3.5/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.3.253
            nameservers:
                addresses: [208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            dhcp4: no
            interfaces:
                - eno1
                - enp2s0
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                primary: eno1
```

Now when I log in I get:

```
IP address for enp2s0:  192.168.3.96
IP address for eno1:    192.168.3.96
IP address for bond0:   192.168.3.5
```

and ifconfig gives me (abridged):

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 xxx:a31d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xxx:a3:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eno1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.96  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        ether xxx:a3:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

enp2s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.96  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        ether xxx:a3:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

I am sure that, before the bond was set, one of the two MACs ended with `:a3:1c`

Did I make mistakes while setting the bond, or is this an intended behaviour?

Edit

I had to reinstall and this is the file that the installer generated for my same configuration, including the bond:

```
network:
    bonds:
        bond0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.3.5/24
            gateway4: 192.168.3.253
            interfaces:
            - eno1
            - enp2s0
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
    ethernets:
        eno1: {}
        enp2s0: {}
    version: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor edits... watch the indents, spacing, and no tabs...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      optional: true
    enp2s0:
      optional: true
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [en01, enp2s0]
      addresses: [192.168.3.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.3.253 # are you sure it's .253?
      nameservers:
        addresses: [208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eno1
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # insure proper operation

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try it. For future reference and clarity for other people reading: do you mean the reason of the IP address allocated also to the single interfaces was caused by the indentation? and what about the MAC addresses? It would be nice to update the answer with these information.

Comment: I tried, it worked.

Comment: @FarO I'm glad it worked for you. The only thing you need to check is the .253 address. yaml files are very fussy about their format. I changed that, added the renderer, added the "optional: true" so there wouldn't be any boot delay, removed the dhcp4 statements as "no" is the default, and reformatted it correctly. It would be instructive to see what IP/MAC addresses you get now.

Comment: .253 was intended, it's a legacy from a previous setup. I get now no IP on the single interfaces and 192.168.3.5 on the bond0, as expected. The MAC is for all the three set to xxx:a3:1d. The MAC of the second interface (xxx:a3:1c) is therefore lost... but I understand: for the failover to work, the MACs must be the same. BTW, the renderer is not required.